# Wireless USB detection problem

Tags: 12.04, usb, 64-bit, mouse, lts

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit, and a Logitech M705 wireless mouse.  The laptop has 3 USB ports; left, right, and back.  When the mouse dongle is plugged in to the back or left UBS port on startup it works fine.  When plugged into the right it doesn't.

If I start up with the dongle disconnected and try to plug it in to any port, it works on all except the right one.

Once the mouse is working on the left or back, if I disconnect the dongle and place it in the right USB port, the right one works!  However, if I reboot it stops working again until I repeat the process.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's some good information on USB power and Linux kernel problems here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206614/usb-slots-stop-working-suddenly-from-time-to-time . Have a look and see if there's anything helpful for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on talking to others, the thought was that this all was because I had the dongle plugged in to the right port when I did a fresh ubuntu-only install a few days ago (just switched from Win7 dual boot setup to ubuntu only).  Since I didn't have a bunch of new programs and data installed yet, I just completely installed ubuntu from scratch again without the dongle in.  Voila!!! Problem solved.  Don't know why, though.

Any thoughts about how I could have fixed this without reinstalling?

P.S.  Looked at response from fabricator4, wasn't very helpful.  However, thanks for the fast response.