# Mouse won't click in newly installed Lubuntu 14

Tags: lubuntu, mouse

First, I'm a simple user of this wonderful OS. So please take it easy on me.

I felt Ubuntu 14.04 was too heavy for my machine (EEE PC 1015CX) and switched to Lubuntu 14(...04 I guess...), it ran perfectly.

Except for the fact that after around one min after booting my mouse and sometimes keyboard stops working properly - mouse won't click (more often left button) and keyboard sometimes won't type even when I am in e.g. address bar. Or system kind of freezes(I can't judge, cause mouse doesn't click, keyboard won't always type or allow commands like CTRL ESC), but when I manage to log out and in again, it again starts to work fine for a moment.

Is there a cure for that? I tried sudo...update and upgrade, but it didn't help.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Check this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/206614/usb-slots-stop-working-suddenly-from-time-to-time

Comment: Have you tried a different mouse or are you talking about the touchpad giving you problems.  My old EeePC 1000 has touchpad problems but that is due to age.  It sometimes refuses to left click for a while.  I solved that by installing a wireless mouse.

Comment: Yes, it's mouse. My touch pad is defunct since I put my laptop through the X-ray machine in airport. And yet haven't tried other mouse...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
metacity --replace
```

If you are using comzip

```
compiz --replace
```

Else try for newer version on Lubuntu

```
unity --replace
```

Also try with alternate mouse. Sometimes mouse could also be an issue

Comment: I have tried all 3, it says neither of those is installed and offers to install via sudo ...