# USB ports not working all of a sudden

Tags: usb

I work with Ubuntu Studio 14.04 since an year, and I never had issues related to USB ports.

Now, since a week or so, all of my USB ports (two 2.0 and one 3.0) stopped working. Initially this happened only sometimes, and a reboot could fix it. Now, since three days, it happens all the times.

I know it's a linux problem and not an hardware one since I have a dual-boot (the other OS being Windows 8) and in Windows everything works fine. Also, in the boot screen I can see that the USB ports work since the red light in my mouse is lit, and it shuts down after I boot Ubuntu Studio.

Of course I want this to revert back to normal.

Do you have suggestions?

**EDIT 1: (15/09/2015)**

Further tests showed that while `Linux version 3.13.0-61` always workss, both in `generic` and `lowlatency` mode, `Linux version 3.13.0-62` and `Linux version 3.13.0-63` usually don't, even though sometimes, randomly, they'll do. This happens both in `lowlatency` and `generic` modes.

I was suggested to upload a full output of `sudo dmesg`. Notice that apparently the terminal is not long enough to show all the message, but [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12418211/)'s the output of a working 3.13.0-61 generic kernel, and [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12418216/)'s the output of 3.13.0-63 lowlatency one.

**EDIT 2: (16/09/2015)**

Here's the complete output of `sudo dmesg`:

- [3.13.0-63-lowlatency (not working)](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12425889/)
- [3.13.0-61-lowlatency (working)](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12425881/)

Here is the shortened version, with just the things referring to USB ports:

- [3.13.0-63-lowlatency (not working)](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12425940/)
- [3.13.0-61-lowlatency (working)](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12425895/)

Comment: Try using a previous kernel. While booting, go to advanced options and select a older kernel.

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206614/usb-slots-stop-working-suddenly-from-time-to-time)

Comment: Curiously, if I start Ubuntu from the "advanced optons" tab, it always work, even though I select the fist one, which happens to be this one:

`Linux version 3.13.0-63-lowlatency (buildd@lgw01-18) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #103-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 14 22:23:32 UTC 2015`. That's the same that should be booted via "the normal way".

I notice that sometimes, when I start Ubuntu the normal way, all the icons on the desktop gets messed up. I don't know if this might somehow be related.

Is there a way I can report these issues?

Comment: @Ravan that's not the case: none of the things connected to the drives work, except the fan. Also, it doesn't happen when I'm already using the computer; it happens only on startup.

Comment: It would help to see the full output of `sudo dmesg` after such a total USB bus failure. You'll probably want to upload it to http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ or similar and include a link in your question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster there it is

Comment: Can you please [capture the entire output of `dmesg`](/a/420983/175814)? You can also filter the lines referring to the USB subsystem like this: `sudo dmesg | grep -i -e '\<usb\>' -e '\<[uoex]hci'`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster and there it is

Comment: Thanks. Though I don't know, what could be the cause of the issue, I'm sure, that this info is crucial for someone more experienced in this area to detect it. Since the problem was very likely caused by a minor change in the kernel, this looks like a bug to me, that you should [report](/q/673700), but that is [off topic](/help/on-topic) on AU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registered User correctly suggested that this problem was related to the kernel.

He was right. The `Linux version 3.13.0-63-lowlatency (buildd@lgw01-18) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #103-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 14 22:23:32 UTC 2015` kernel is the one giving problems. I guess it's not fully compatible with Acer Aspire E 15 computers.

The best working kernel seems to be this one: `Linux version 3.13.0-61-generic (buildd@lgw01-50) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 29 11:21:34 UTC 2015`.