# Usb devices stop working after some period of time

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 last week.  I first installed Linux mint, but switched to Ubuntu to try and resolve my issues with the keyboard and mouse, same issue persisted into Ubuntu.

I have a Logitech mouse and no name keyboard both with wireless nano receivers. They work perfectly for a while - could be an hour could be 3 hour, but then stop responding until I reboot. I have have had them stop working while I surfed the web.

A couple of days ago I started a tail of the syslog on my terminal in hopes of catching the error message or disable message ..something.  But i discovered that leaving the terminal up tailing a log file my problem goes away.  If I turn off the tail of the log sure enough my mouse and keyboard lock up eventually. So tailing a log file is causing something to occur re usb disable that surfing the web does not...

It seems that the activity of outputting the log file to a screen is keeping my usb ports active. Does anyone know of some script i can run via cron to keep the same type of activity going so I don't lose my keyboard and mouse?  I have read this is a bug and people have tried many settings that don't work. I think if there is a way to have cron run a script that has the same effect as running tail on a logfile in a terminal window does, my problem will be worked around.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

I hope this is clear, please ask for any information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB slots stop working suddenly from time to time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206614/usb-slots-stop-working-suddenly-from-time-to-time)