# Android Phone 6 not detected after improper removal Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, android, connection

So I installed the drivers for my phone (Mediatek) and then I connected it through usb cable after which was recognized by my PC. I transferred some files from the PC to the phone and after it was done, I left it plugged into the PC for it to charge. After a few moments, I accidentally pulled the usb cable from the laptop's USB port. The device was still displayed on the taskbar (the one on the left side of the desktop) but when I tried to open it, it displayed an error message which stated that the device is not connected. I reconnected it again but my PC did not recognize it anymore.

EDIT: I already tried rebooting but still doesn't recognize my phone

Comment: Well, I have such an experience on FreeBSD but not Ubuntu. On FreeBSD sometimes my usd device is not recognized, then I have to `power_off` the usb port and then `power_on` it again with command `usbconfig`. I'm not sure if it can help you, but maybe you can get a hint

Comment: Hmm based on what you said and what I researched in the internet maybe restarting the USB ports may be the fix for this. I'm still finding a question for restarting undetected usb ports, though most questions are mostly malfunctioning usb devices. Very much obliged for your tip!

Comment: I tried to do 'dmesg' from https://askubuntu.com/questions/178054/laptop-usb-ports-stop-working-how-to-restart-them-without-restarting-the-pc
and as I skimmed through I noticed this error message in the usb portion
[    9.706604] usb 3-2: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[    9.706637] usb usb3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The device does not show up  when I try `lsusb`. From memory, I remembered it was a Mediatek device, but it does not show up in the list.

Comment: While searching through Google, I came up with the idea that maybe reinstalling the drivers may help resolve this problem, since that's what I do most of the time when I was still using Windows. Can this also be a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the idea of trying other usb cables attempted to do one and it did work. It was all just a hardware problem after all.